# Why does all of the sprites I make appear huge when I put them into Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, size, sprite

I make sprites in Krita and when I export them I make them .pngs. For some reason when I import these sprites into Unity they are huge and not nearly the size they should be. Why does this happen? Does it have something to do with the exports? And should I be using a better art software than Krita? Please let me know it's really annoying to make the sprites   at like 0.1x size just to make it appear normal.

Comment: Sprites have a "pixels per unit" setting that you'll likely need to adjust.